# Trying to open a file with Eclipe - eclipse.exe isn't added to the Open With: window

Tags: java, eclipse, file-association

Thoughts on fixing this?

I'm trying to open my .project file for a homework assignment and the Open With: program (?) doesn't seem to be detecting Eclipse at all.

It works perfectly fine on my laptop, but I use my desktop as my main machine and thus need it to work on here.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Probably eclipse doesn't associate your project files to itself. Try to search eclipse on window "Open With" make sure the checkbox "Aways use this program...." is checked.

Comment: Do you have such `file association` set on your desktop?

Comment: Well, that's the thing. Whenever I go to the "Open With:" windows, I'll find eclipse but then it won't actually show up inside the window in order to have the file open with it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the .project file to start Eclipse.

Start eclipse from the main start menu shortcut or eclipse.exe.
Then select the workspace (browse to it) you want to work in (and that contains your project).
If your project is not in a workspace, import it with the eclipse import menu.

Comment: This does not address OP's point that the same approach "works perfectly fine" on his/her laptop.

Comment: It is just an advice :) I think his question is answered in one of the questions comments

Comment: Seems to be a bit off-topic.

Comment: Maybe, I only care if it helps to solve the problem, sometimes the question is wrong

Comment: If I want to open a program/project I have to open eclipse first.

Comment: However, that doesn't solve my problem that eclipse won't show up in the Open With window. :|

Comment: Open eclipse first is the recomended way. However if you still want to use the "open with" windows, I think you can click on the "Browse..." button and look for the eclipse.exe program